# How to efficiently delete multiple columns in a huge dataframe Python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe that consists of 75750 columns.
I'm trying to automatically  grab 5 specific columns because I need the data from each of those 5 columns to generate a plot.
I'm using a for loop which is incredibly slow.
The  max_list contains 5 labels, that are generated, so I don't know what columns each label might refer to in the huge data frame. So the columns can't be selected manually or be known before the max_list is generated.

```
   max_list = ["column7000", "column200", "column15000", "column30", "column2"]

   for i in max_frame.columns:
    if i not in max_list:
        del max_frame[i]
```

The code works, but it takes foreveeeer! And no other code will run until it's finished running. 
I've tried to get cython, but it won't work properly. I'm using the latest version of Jupyter notebook with Python 3.6.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not really understand, what you want to do....but if you want to find elements fast, dictionaries are much better than lists.

Comment: You can easily subset by columns: `newdf = df[max_list]`

Comment: Hey dede, thanks, I'll take a look into dictionaries.

Comment: Holy moly, thanks Parfait, you saved my life!

Comment: Also if you are not using all of your columns, you can drop the redundant columns while reading the data with `usecols` argument.

Comment: also `df.drop` and @YakymPirozhenko he doesn't know the columns before hand according to his post

Comment: Thank you everyone, very kind. Yep, I don't know what columns to select beforehand, it's part of an algo I'm trying to write. Sorry if I didn''t articulate my trouble clearly. I think my del code is best to be avoided unless it's for small dataframes cause it's super slow.

Answer (score 1):

Understand a bit of the problem, Suppose we want to slice all the columns except the columns in the max_list and we may be having many columns and rows in a dataset.

During iteration we are going to remove the item which is not in the list and add to the desired new list.

```
max_list = ["column7000", "column200", "column15000", "column30", "column2"]

max_frame_1 = max_frame[:]   # let's take a copy of actual dataset

desired = [max_frame_1.remove(item) for item in max_frame_1 if not in max_list]
```

If this works, hope this is the shortest and quick method.

Moreover, when we have lots of data and the workout is less, we need to try to be as simple as possible.